# Add border around word without changing formatting ? HTML

Tags: html, outlook, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to add a border around ATTENTION. However, whenever i use it, the formatting of the whole text changes and it's out of context.
This is the original text

```html
<p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: 14.0pt; background: white;" align="center"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'MarkOT-HeavyItalic',sans-serif; mso-bidi-font-family: Calibri; color: red; mso-bidi-font-style: italic;">ATTENTION: This email came from an external source. This email came from an external source This email came from an external source.&nbsp;This email came from an external source <a href="mailto:aaaa">example@example.com</a></span></p>
<p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: 14.0pt; background: white;" align="center"><span style="font-size: 14.0pt; font-family: 'MarkOT-HeavyItalic',sans-serif; mso-bidi-font-family: Calibri; color: red; mso-bidi-font-style: italic;"><span style="mso-spacerun: yes;">&nbsp;</span></span></p>
```

I would like ATTENTION to look like this without changing the formatting of the rest of the text, any way to do this ?

```html
<table border="2" style="height: 10px; width: 13.3803%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: yellow;" height="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100%;">ATTENTION:</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hey guys, so  @abhijat_saxena is on point, but in outlook application on windows this is how it looks, any way to fill the white space so it's completely yellow ? 
[Outlook app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ2I5.png)

Comment: check my answer - it's close to what you wanted

Comment: Yeap, that's it. I just didn't know how to keep the formatting, it kept changing. Thanks ! I will mark your answer as correct, I'm just waiting to remove my personal email (forgot to remove it). Thanks again!

Comment: removed your personal email address, please check

Comment: Thanks @abhijat_saxena , I have one more question, can you take a look at the photo I uploaded ? The yellow part is not filling up the whole border in the outlook app on windows. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I think that's because of the 2px padding that has been added  I have edited my solution - can you try again ?

Comment: That did it, i set the padding to 0px and it's gone! Thanks !

Comment: request you to mark my solution as the right answer.

Comment: Will do, just waiting for @Nazeeh or someone from community to approve my edit of his answer - i tried to remove the personal email. I don't want it to impact the ability to edit answers. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style is applied to the entire text, to keep style for a specific areas - use span tags

```html
<p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: 14.0pt; background: white;" align="center"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'MarkOT-HeavyItalic',sans-serif; mso-bidi-font-family: Calibri; color: red; mso-bidi-font-style: italic;"><span style="border:1px solid #000; background-color: yellow;">ATTENTION:</span> This email came from an external source. This email came from an external source This email came from an external source.&nbsp;This email came from an external source <a href="mailto:">example@example.com</a></span></p>
<p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: 14.0pt; background: white;" align="center"><span style="font-size: 14.0pt; font-family: 'MarkOT-HeavyItalic',sans-serif; mso-bidi-font-family: Calibri; color: red; mso-bidi-font-style: italic;"><span style="mso-spacerun: yes;">&nbsp;</span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: 14.0pt; background: white;" align="center"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'MarkOT-HeavyItalic',sans-serif; mso-bidi-font-family: Calibri; color: red; mso-bidi-font-style: italic;"><span style="border:1px solid #000; padding:2px">ATTENTION:</span> This email came from an external source. This email came from an external source This email came from an external source.&nbsp;This email came from an external source <a href="mailto:a">example@example.com</a></span></p>
<p style="margin: 0in; margin-bottom: .0001pt; text-align: center; line-height: 14.0pt; background: white;" align="center"><span style="font-size: 14.0pt; font-family: 'MarkOT-HeavyItalic',sans-serif; mso-bidi-font-family: Calibri; color: red; mso-bidi-font-style: italic;"><span style="mso-spacerun: yes;">&nbsp;</span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Attention text into span and then style it by css file of inline on your choice.

```css
.attention{
background: yellow;
border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table style="height: 10px; width: 13.3803%; border-collapse: collapse;" height="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 100%;"><span class="attention">ATTENTION:</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```